# Building Ros 2.0 without OpenCV?

Tags: ros2, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to build Ros 2.0 without having to have OpenCV installed.

Is this possible / How would I do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217546/building-ros-2.0-without-opencv?/) by [Sam101](https://answers.ros.org/users/23848/sam101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-09-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Slightly longer answer. Touch a file AMENT_IGNORE in the packages that use opencv and they will be ignored in the build.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1